# Specifing references for xbuild on the command line (or some other place than the project file)

Tags: linux, mono

I have a xamarin-forms PCL solution which also contains a NUnit project, which tests only non-GUI aspects.

I am developing under windows.

Now I want to run the NUnit tests on linux (using mono) on my CI server.

For this I need to compile the PCL project and the NUnit project (and *not* the android and iOS).

When running xbuild inside the NUnit project, it tells me:

```
AppTests.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `MY_App' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

(MY_App is the name of the PCL project).
Now I can add:

```
<Reference Include="My_App">
  <HintPath>..\My-App\MY_App\bin\Release\MY_App.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

And it works!

My question: Is there another way than adjusting the project files for linux? The primary purpose of these project files is to be used from visual studio. Can I somehow specify the reference on the command line or in an extra file?

Comment: Does your `NUnit` project have a *project* reference to your `MY_App.csproj`?

Comment: There is not. Should visual studio add that for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a hardcoded assembly (via an `<Reference>` element), add a **project**-based reference for your `MY_App.csproj` to your `NUnit`-based project. This can be done via the IDE (Visual Studio, Xamarin Studio,....), or by manually editing the `.csproj` file.

You will end up with a `ProjectReference` that looks something like:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\RealmLoginKitTest\RealmLoginKitTest.csproj">
  <Project>{6524A097-D064-4933-987F-76EB19AF3F57}</Project>
  <Name>RealmLoginKitTest</Name>
  <ReferenceOutputAssembly>False</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
</ProjectReference>
```

Now when you use `xbuild|MSBuild` to build your `NUnit`-based project, it will also build the referenced project and include its build artifacts in the NUnit project's output directory (assuming you have not turned local copy off (false), which would have placed a `<Private>False</Private>` element in the `Reference` section for this project.